# FTP- Find modified files of particular date in filezilla

Tags: ftp, file-search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6fop.png)we have a magento e commerce site.

we are having hundered of folders and sub folders and thousands of files.

we want to know that files which are modified on a particular date.

i am following this link which is using Remote search.

: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-use-remote-file-search-in-filezilla-325/

but i am able to get files only in particular folder. i want to search the files in all folders.

its impossible to check by giving path of each folder manually in remote file search.

I want to find edited files of all folders and sub folders

please help me to find some solution.

Comment: this really isn't a question you should be attempting to answer client side. why not get the data from the server end?

Comment: i am new to this technology, can you please guide me on this ?

Comment: ok, that kind of answers that question. I take it asking your IT guy is not a possibility? You link indicates that filezilla will search the root directory and all sub-directories in it. Since FTP servers usually have a single root directory, it shouldn't be too difficult to do as you suggest.

Comment: actually lot of files are there in sub directory, its searching only sub directory, not the files modified under sub directory. this is the problem.

Comment: Seems like a trivial task. So I assume you are doing some trivial mistake. A screenshot of your "Remote file search" window may help us understand what you are doing wrong. (Or possibly understand why your task is not as trivial as it seems to me).

Comment: i updated the question with image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the root of your search in the *Search directory* box.

Or easier, navigate to the root folder in the FileZilla remote panel and open the *Remote file search window*. The *Search directory* will be populated with the current remote directory.

Comment: please check edited question, is there any way to get files of sub folders also?

Comment: It does search sub folders. If not, show us a screenshot with the results with missing files as well as a screenshot of the main file panel with the file that you believe should be in the results.